# ¿Cómo puedo mantener el orden de los argumentos por consola dentro del namespace en el modulo argparse de python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Pasa que por consola hago:

```
a = avion

b = beto

c = casa

d = duvan

python script.py -a 1 -b 2 -c 3 -d 4
```

y en el *namespace* se me guarda en desorden a como los agregue es decir:

```
namespace(duvan = 4 , beto = 2 , avion = 1, casa = 3)
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que el *namespace* me guarde los valores tal cual como los agregue por la terminal?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El [`Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) no es más que un simple objeto que almacena como atributos los argumentos y proporciona una forma de acceder a ellos.

Internamente todos los objetos python almacenan sus atributos en un diccionario, y ocurre que hasta hace muy poco *los diccionarios python no garantizan el orden*.

En Python 3.7, debido a cómo estaban implementados, resultaba que sí que el iterar por un diccionario te devolvía sus elementos en el mismo orden en que fueron insertados, pero se consideraba una feliz casualidad de la implementación, y no una característica del lenguaje, por lo tanto no deberían hacerse programas que dependieran de esto, ya que en futuras versiones podría variar.

A partir de Python 3.8 los diccionarios ya preservan oficialmente el orden de inserción, y en versiones futuras seguirán preservándolo.

Entiendo por tanto que bastará que uses Python 3.7+ para que el `Namespace` te devuelva los elementos en orden de inserción.

Si trabajas con una versión previa de Python, el orden de inserción no es preservado, pero puedes ordenarlos alfabéticamente, si te sirve. Al menos en este caso así sería:

```
for arg in sorted(vars(namespace)):
    print(arg, namespace.get(arg))
```

Comment: Que es ese sorted?

Comment: me ordena los parámetros por la inicial, pero no tiene en cuenta el orden de los argumentos cuando los inserto en el cmd :/